# Accessing ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeObject>> elements

Tags: java, arraylist, genetic-algorithm

I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s where i need to find a simple way of accessing the elements, to make it easier to understand i have drawn my goal of what i want to achieve:

[image]

As seen on the image above the main `ArrayList` consists of **m** `ArrayList`, where i wish to get an element by using a `get` method which goes from 0 to **N** elements, where **N** is the total elements of `ArrayList1` and `ArrayList2`. More ArrayList's may occur.

I can of course iterate through the elements by using two for-loops, which is not what im searching for in this case.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid nested loops in this case? Complexity?

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp, i want to avoid the complexity as you mention. I am already using nested loops but its making my application extremely slow.

Comment: Why do you need such a structure, ArrayList of ArrayList, if you want to access it as though it was flat anyway?

Comment: @Patashu, long story short i am programming a genetic algorithm. The root ArrayList is a `generation` consisting of ArrayList which are `populations`.

Comment: @JavaCake: but what prevents you from copying all the elements of every list to a single one containing everything?

Comment: Or why not just pass two int's for the index?

Comment: @JBNizet, keeping all my `populations` seperated.

Comment: @ChrisCooney, can you please clarify that answer.

Comment: You could have both : the list of lists you have now, AND another list containing all the elements of all the lists.

Comment: @JBNizet, that sounds messy. How is that possible without making this too complex?

Comment: @JavaCake instead of passing say, `4`, pass `3,5`. `3` being the index of the arraylist, and `5` being the index inside that arraylist.

Comment: I don't see how it's messy. Encapsulate that into a class.

Comment: @ChrisCooney, it requires major modifications in my exisiting code, but this could be an alternative. I will keep it as a potentiale solution.

Comment: @JBNizet, can you pass an example on this method?

Comment: Iterating through one larger `for`-loop would be just as slow as iterating through smaller nested `for`-loops, since the number of elements are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to basically have the the `ArrayList` members on your new wrapper class and implement them in a different manner. I whipped up an example that demonstrates the correct index being calculated in `get()`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListHolder<T> {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            size += list.get(i).size();
        }
        return size;
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        if (i >= size())
            return null;

        int listIndex = 0;
        int valueIndex = i;

        while (valueIndex >= list.get(listIndex).size()) {
            valueIndex -= list.get(listIndex++).size();
        }

        return list.get(listIndex).get(valueIndex);
    }
}
```

What I used to verify my methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ListHolder<Object> listHolder = new ListHolder<Object>();

    listHolder.list.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
    listHolder.list.get(0).add("hello");
    listHolder.list.get(0).add("world");

    listHolder.list.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
    listHolder.list.get(1).add("a");
    listHolder.list.get(1).add("b");
    listHolder.list.get(1).add("c");

    System.out.println("Size: " + listHolder.size());
    System.out.println("listHolder[0]: " + listHolder.get(0)); // "hello"
    System.out.println("listHolder[1]: " + listHolder.get(1)); // "world"
    System.out.println("listHolder[2]: " + listHolder.get(2)); // "a"
    System.out.println("listHolder[3]: " + listHolder.get(3)); // "b"
    System.out.println("listHolder[4]: " + listHolder.get(4)); // "c"
    System.out.println("listHolder[5]: " + listHolder.get(5)); // "null"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide many details about what these lists are, and if they're mutable or not. But you could probably use an additional list containing all the elements of all the sublists:

```
private class Generation
    private List<List<Element>> populations = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Element> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public Element getElementAt(int elementIndex) {
        return allElements.get(elementIndex);
    }

    public void addPopulation(List<Element> population) {
        populations.add(new ArrayList<>(population));
        allElements.addAll(population);
    }

    public List<Element> getPopulationAt(int populationIndex) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(populations.get(populationIndex));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Plot {
 class Point {
   int x;
   int y;
 }

 List<List<Point>> area = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();

 Point getPoint (int x, int y) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
   if (x < 0 && x >= area.size())
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
   int l = area.get(x).size();
   int i = (int)y/l;
   int j = y % l;
   return area.get(x+i).get(j);
 }

 void setPoint (int x, int y, Point p) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
   if (x < 0 && x >= area.size())
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
   int l = area.get(x).size();
   int i = (int)y/l;
   int j = y % l;
   area.get(x+i).set(j, p);
 }
}
```

Comment: The second `ArrayList` in the area statement should be `List`. The generic types must be identical.  But in Java 7, just use <>.